# Monolog Elasticsearch configuration in Symfony

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, monolog

I tried to configure Elasticsearch for monolog as mentioned [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/handlers.html) but the problem is that I don't find any way to pass my username and password for Elasticsearch since the ElasticsearchLogstashHandler service only takes an endpoint as input.

here's the service that I created:

```
elasticsearch_logstash_handler:
    class: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ElasticsearchLogstashHandler
    arguments: [ '%ELASTIC_SEARCH_ENDPOINT%']
```

I tried to put username and password in the URL (username:password@url) but since the password contains special characters it doesn't work this way.

thank you for sharing your ideas.

Comment: I think you should add them in the header (Authorization: Basic username:password) of the request to elasticsearch.

Comment: @TimZwinkels the service takes a HttpClient as input, should I include headers in a custom client and pass it to the service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a http client with basic auth, this can be done in packages/framework.yaml:

```
framework:
     http_client:
        scoped_clients:
            es.client:
                base_uri: http://host.docker.internal:9200
                auth_basic: "%env(string:ELASTICSEARCH_USER)%:%env(string:ELASTICSEARCH_PASS)%"
```

Add the client to your handler in services.yaml:

```
    Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ElasticsearchLogstashHandler:
      arguments:
        $endpoint: http://host.docker.internal:9200
        $index: your-log-index-in-es
        $client: "@es.client"
        $level: error
        $bubble: true
        $elasticsearchVersion: 8.8.1
```

Finally, add the handler to packages/monolog.yaml:

```
    monolog:
      handlers:
        elasticsearch:
            type: service
            id: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ElasticsearchLogstashHandler
            level: error
            channels: ["!event"]
            ignore_error: false
```